# RailsInstaller on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, railsinstaller, railsinstaller-windows

I tried to use the [Rails Installer](http://www.railsinstaller.org/) to get a *ruby on rails* environment on my **Windows 7 64bit** today and the *.exe* won't run because it's made for 32bit instead of 64bit.

**Update** When I try to start the installer, this message pops up:

[image]

Here is the translation:

> This version of the file is not compatible with the running version of Windows.
>   Open the system information of the computer to check if a x86 (32bit) or x64 
>   (64bit) version of this application is neccessary and contact the software vendor.

Is there a 64bit alternative for the installer?

Comment: The linked download on railsinstaller.org works perfectly on Windows 7 x64. What is the error/problem you are getting?

Comment: Wow, that's strange. Is there a MD5 checksum I can compare with my download?

Answer (score 2):

64bits Windows can run 32bits applications, that is what WOW64 layer provides (Windows on Windows)

However, there are specific things you can't perform, like accessing OLE or using 64bits DLLs from 32bits applications or viceversa.

If the issue you're having is connect to a MySQL installation (something you're not mentioning) you should take a look to this blog article:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, I'll add that information. But I don't think it's the mysql part of the installation, because an error message pops up as soon as I run the installer exe.

Comment: @cringe: I have Windows 7 x64 and I was able to successfully install RailsInstaller 2.0, so I believe could be a possible corrupt download?